# Is there a good way to summarize multiple graphs in one?

Tags: math, data-structures, graph, tree

Suppose I have 2 graphs. These graphs contain several components: blocks, nodes, and edges. Each block has its own list of nodes and each node has a batch of edges. Furthermore, edges have incremental identities (1, 2, 3, 4...), and the same stands for the other components of the graphs. Also, edges have float values.

For example:

**Structure of "Graph 1":**

```
Graph1 -> Block[id=1] -> Node[id=1] -> Edge[id=1,value=5]
Graph1 -> Block[id=2] -> Node[id=2] -> Edge[id=2,value=7]
```

(this graph has 2 blocks and each block has 1 node with 1 edge in it)

**Structure of "Graph 2":**

```
Graph2 -> Block[id=1] -> Node[id=1] -> Edge[id=1,value=15]
Graph2 -> Block[id=2] -> Node[id=2] -> Edge[id=2,value=17]
```

My task is to find a sum of the edges' values with ids 1 and 2 between graphs and do it as fast as possible.

**The result should be like the below:**

```
ResultGraph -> Block[id=1] -> Node[id=1] -> Edge[id=1,value=5+15]
ResultGraph -> Block[id=2] -> Node[id=2] -> Edge[id=2,value=7+17]
```

How can I do that? Which algorithm should I use?

The only idea I have is to iterate trough the graphs and find the sum. However, there should be a better approach...

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the performance of this particular task you need to store the edge values in a multimap ( https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/ ) with the key being the edge ID and the value being the edge value.

This allows you to iterate very quickly over the edges, and only the edges, that have a specified ID.

```
SET total = 0
ITERATE i over required edge IDs ( e.g. 1,2 )
   ITERATE e over edges that have ID == i
       total += e's value
```

So, when you are adding edges to the graph ( storing them in whatever data structure you use for other things ) also populate the multimap as described.  This will slow down the addition of edges as the multimap sorts them into order.  However, it will greatly speed up the particular task so if you have to perform the task several time there will be net gain in performance.

**Another approach**

You can avoid the iteration entirely by storing the total value for each edge ID in an array as the edges are added.  Then you can find the totals for each ID with a single lookup and sum the required edge ID totals.

This is fast and uses less memory than the multimap.  The snag is things get a bit more complex if the edge values change.  Then you have to subtract the old edge value from the stored total before adding the new value.